# Android Layout problems - not display anything

Tags: android

I am doing a Apps function that can upload files.

after finish all the debug and start the program

the LogCat didnt show anything about error.

But it just a blank white page.

Please help, i have no idea whats happen.

java code:

```
package com.example.adc;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.nio.charset.Charset;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody;
        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
        import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private void doMultiPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> params){
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
     try{
      //setup multipart entity
      MultipartEntity entity = new  MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

      for(int i=0;i< params.size();i++){
      //identify param type by Key
      if(params.get(i).getName().equals("file")){
       File f=new File(params.get(i).getValue());
       FileBody fileBody=new FileBody(f);
       entity.addPart("image"+i,fileBody);
      }else{
       entity.addPart(params.get(i).getName(),new StringBody(params.get(i).getValue(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      }
      }

      post.setEntity(entity);

      //create response handler
      ResponseHandler <String> handler=new BasicResponseHandler();
      //execute and get response
      String response=new String(client.execute(post,handler).getBytes(),HTTP.UTF_8);
      Toast.makeText(this, response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
      }     
    }

public void onSubmit(View v){
     String path = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.filePath)).getText().toString();
     String des = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.desTxt)).getText().toString();

     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file",path));
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("des",des));

     doMultiPost("10.0.0.2/MultipartPost.php",params);
    }   
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.adc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   >


  <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView
   android:layout_width="130dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="file Description:"/>

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/desTxt" 
  android:layout_width="160dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
   android:layout_width="130dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="File path:"/>

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/filePath" 
  android:layout_width="160dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
 </LinearLayout>

 <Button 
   android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Submit"
   android:onClick="onSubmit"    
 />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the `onCreate()` method inside activity?

Comment: There is no `onCreate()`. LOL...

Comment: `onCreate()` is the only relevant method.  Please post that method.

Comment: @nhgrif He forgot to Override `onCreate()`.

Comment: It is so easy to just copy and paste the whole code on stackoverflow rather than researching and doing it ownself.

Comment: So  whats the problem ?   i saw a solutions that delete tge onCreate() will fix the problem looool

Comment: @user2900491 Lol.. really??? In Android `onCreate()` is everythinggg.......

Comment: Thank you for you help!   I will learn to understand their and do it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your Activity..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
}
```

And voila...

Comment: @user2900491 It does obviously. I was not criticizing at all and keep in mind it you will learn from your mistakes. Your welcome.

Comment: The problem is fixed, but cant upload the file :(
but thank you i will keep practice

Comment: Check this http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: Yes, It works.  But i will rebuild the problem by understand this Program. Thank you very much!